# Unable to log in or create users in MediaWiki

Tags: php, security, mediawiki

I am *unable* **to log in / create a New user in a MediaWiki** wiki.

- It throws the error:
  `Account creation error: Incorrect password entered. Please try again.`
- Or when I try to log in:
  `Log-in error :Incorrect password entered. Please try again.`

---

Based on the help documents in MediaWiki added the below code in the localsettings.php file.

I have also  added the php-ldap service though command prompt in my local ubuntu machine.

## LDAP Settings in Local Settings.php

```
require_once 'extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php';
require_once 'includes/AuthPlugin.php';
$wgAuth = new LdapAuthenticationPlugin();
$wgLDAPDomainNames = array(
  'MDomain',
);

$wgLDAPServerNames = array(
  'MDomain.local' => '10.10.1.6','MDomain-C02.MDomain','MDomain01.MDomain.local',
);
$wgLDAPUseLocal = false;
$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array(
  'MDomain.LOCAL' => 'tls',
);
$wgLDAPPort = array(
  'openldap_example_com' => 389,
);
$wgLDAPProxyAgent = array(
  'MDomain.local' => 'cn=wikimedia-service,dc=MDomain,dc=LOCAL',
);
$wgLDAPProxyAgentPassword = array(
  'MDomain.local' => 'XXXX',
);
$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array(
  'MDomain.local' => 'sAMAccountName'
);
$wgLDAPBaseDNs = array(
  'MDomain.local' => 'ou=MDomain,dc=MDomain,dc=local',
);
# To pull e-mail address from LDAP
$wgLDAPPreferences = array(
  'MDomain.local' => array( 'email' => 'mail')
);
# Group based restriction
$wgLDAPGroupUseFullDN = array( "MDomain.local"=>false );
$wgLDAPGroupObjectclass = array( "MDomain.local"=>"Group" );
$wgLDAPGroupAttribute = array( "MDomain.local"=>"memberuid" );
$wgLDAPGroupSearchNestedGroups = array( "MDomain.local"=>true );
$wgLDAPGroupNameAttribute = array( "MDomain.local"=>"cn" );
$wgLDAPRequiredGroups = array( "MDomain.local"=>array("cn=wikimedia-service,dc=MDomain,dc=local"));
$wgLDAPLowerCaseUsername = array(
  'MDomain.local' => true,
);
```

Can you please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: Please document your MediaWiki and plugin version, [debug information](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug), steps taken to test your LDAP setup...

Comment: Does password reset work?